# Write a Java program that interacts with Iphone,Ipod, or Ipad in order to sync files(music,books,photos)? in much the same way Itunes does

Tags: java, ios

I know that to develop applications for Iphone using Java and a windows PC will not work, but what I want to know if there is a library or way to communicate to a connected Iphone/Ipod/Ipad to sync songs and music. In the same way itunes syncs music and photos. I assume this is a possible task since you would be interacting with the Iphone as it were a portable device rather than writing an application that installs on the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ya sure can. Check this out:
http://www.codenameone.com/

Open source and you can dev for both Android & iPhone. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, its kind of challenging to word it without people thinking you want to develop for IOS using Java.

Comment: @Martin H, I was speaking to this statement "I know that to develop applications for Iphone using Java and a windows PC will not work"

Comment: @Ducksauce Which is followed immediately by the comment "but what I want to know ..." So you answered what he just stated he knew and didn't answer what he was asking ;-)